# Swift Decode [String: Any]

Tags: swift, encoding, decoding

So I have this API that returns a dictionary of `[String: Any]`, I know that what comes as Any is `Decodable` or an array of `Decodable` however I can't for the life of me figure out how to take that dictionary and decode it to some struct:

What I have goes basically like this:

```
public func call<T: Codable> (completion handler: @escaping (T?) -> ()) {
    let promise = api.getPromise ()
    promise.done (on: DispatchQueue.main, { (results: [String:Any])
        let decodedResults:T? = results.decode (as: T.self) // <-- this is what I want
        handler (decodedResults)
    })
}
```

I've tried turning it to data and then decoding it with:

```
let values = results.compactMap { $0.value }
let data = JSONSerialization.data (withJSONObject: values, options: [])
let decodedResult = JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
```

but it always fails with `NSInvalidArgumentException`, any idea how to get around this?

Another thing that I was trying to achieve but failed to do so is to turn values into a tuple, but for all I could find it's not possible to create tuples dynamically.

Comment: You should change your `api.getPromise()` method to return a `data` promise, instead of `[String: Any]`

Comment: That's not really an option, since the api already decodes the data, which is not composed of swift primitives, into several swift structures, is there any other way or I have no other choice than to go `let address = values[0] as? MyStruct1 `

Comment: I need this too!  Except I need to encode it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decoders convert Data into Decodable values. They don't have anything to do with `[String: Any]` types or any other non-Data type. So if you want to run it through a decoder, you need to convert it to JSON encoded into Data.

If the `[String: Any]` results are exclusively JSONSerialization-safe types (arrays, dictionaries, strings, numbers, null), then `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:options:)` would let you get back to data, so you can re-decode it. Your code doesn't just re-encode its results, it first turns it into an array:

```
let values = results.compactMap { $0.value }
let data = JSONSerialization.data (withJSONObject: values, options: [])
```

That's very strange. Do you really mean to create an array here and throw away the keys? I would then expect your `JSONDecoder().decode()` line to decode `[T].self` rather than `T.self`. So I would expect the following code (provided that your `[String: Any]` is JSON-safe):

```
public func call<T: Decodable>(completion handler: @escaping (T?) -> ()) {
    let promise = api.getPromise()
    promise.done(on: .main) { (results: [String:Any]) in
        guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(results) else {
            handler(nil)
            return
        }

        let data = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: results)
        let decodedResults = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        handler(decodedResults)
    }
}
```

In the comments you note that the decoded data (the `[String: Any]`) is not made of primitives. In that case it's not possible to re-encode it with JSONSerialization. You'll need to pass the `[String: Any]` to something that knows how to deal with it. For example:

```
protocol DictionaryDecodable {
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any])
}

public func call<T: DictionaryDecodable>(completion handler: @escaping (T?) -> ()) {
    let promise = api.getPromise ()
    promise.done(on: .main) { (results: [String:Any])
        handler(T.init(dictionary: results))
    }
}
```

Your types will need to implement an `init?(dictionary:)` that can decode their own values out of a `[String: Any]`.

Comment: That's a shame, I really wanted a more elegant way of solving it but I already had a feeling that that would be the only way, Thanks!