# Type does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I have a class named Event that I want to make it Codable:

```swift
class Event: Codable {
    let name: String
    let action: String
    let data: [String: Any]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case action
        case data
    }

    init(name: String, action: String, data: [String: Any]?) {
        self.name = name
        self.action = action
        self.data = data
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.action = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .action)
        let eventDataAsJSONString = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .data)
        if let eventDataAsData = eventDataAsJSONString.data(using: .utf8) {
            self.data = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: eventDataAsData, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } else {
            self.data = nil
        }
    }

    func encode(from encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(self.action, forKey: .action)
        if let data = self.data {
            let eventDataAsData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [])
            let eventDataAsJSONString = String(data: eventDataAsData, encoding: .utf8)
            try container.encode(eventDataAsJSONString, forKey: .data)
        } else {
            try container.encodeNil(forKey: .data)
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm  getting this error:

```
Type 'Event' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
```

I implemented both `init(from decoder: Decoder)` and `encode(from encoder: Encoder)`.
so what I'm doing wrong here?

### *I need `data` property with `[String:Any]` type, because my users need to store some json-like information with it.*

Comment: You can't use `Any` together with `Codable`, that's what is wrong. What do you mean with "my users"?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have a framework. In this framework's API, there is a method like this: `SomeFramework.shared.sendEvent(event: Event)` that sends that event to a server as a JSON. I have a module that does the job(sending messages to the server) for me with codable objects. because of this reason I'm trying to make event codable.

Comment: Well you can’t do this, decode any arbitrary structure. Maybe take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55047138/swift-decode-string-any)

Comment: I need this too!

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can use ANY in Codable

```
class Event<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let name: String
    let action: String
    let data: [String: T]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case action
        case data
    }

    init(name: String, action: String, data: [String: T]?) {
        self.name = name
        self.action = action
        self.data = data
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.action = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .action)
        let eventDataAsJSONString = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .data)
        if let eventDataAsData = eventDataAsJSONString.data(using: .utf8) {
            self.data = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: eventDataAsData, options: []) as? [String: T]
        } else {
            self.data = nil
        }
    }

    func encode(from encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(self.action, forKey: .action)
        if let data = self.data {
            let eventDataAsData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [])
            let eventDataAsJSONString = String(data: eventDataAsData, encoding: .utf8)
            try container.encode(eventDataAsJSONString, forKey: .data)
        } else {
            try container.encodeNil(forKey: .data)
        }
    }
}


     let event = Event<String>(name: "name", action: "action", data: ["String" : "String"]) // Replace <String> with the type u want and pass that in data
```

Comment: You are not using `Any` in your answer so that claim is incorrect, you are using a generic parameter that is constrained to conform to `Codable` which `Any` doesn't do. I guess instead of using generics one could instead declare `data` to be of type `[String: Codable] `

Comment: @JoakimDanielson replacing codable and any doesn't' works and I get the same error.

Comment: @Nitesh consider data to be like this:
```["first": ["nested": 12.5],
                                                        "second": "ddd",
                                                        "third": 123]```
your answer will not work for this.

Comment: @JafarKhoshtabiat yes I realized later that it wouldn’t work, sorry I forgot to comment on that.