# Problem with test keys of a snapshot.value

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this solution that works, but I don’t want to take any risks with import problems in Firebase. I want to verify that the [Nom], [Prenom], [Club], [Cat], [License] and [Selected] keys exist in dtlSnapdict. I couldn’t find a solution that worked
Do you have an idea
Thank you very much for your help
Best regards
Georges

```
 if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
   
    for dtlSnapdict in snapDict as [String:AnyObject]{
        self.contenuliste.removeAll()
        self.nom = dtlSnapdict.value["Nom"] as! String
        self.prenom = dtlSnapdict.value["Prenom"] as! String
        self.club = dtlSnapdict.value["Club"] as! Int
        self.cat = dtlSnapdict.value["Cat"] as! String
        self.licence = dtlSnapdict.value["Licence"] as! Int
        self.selected = dtlSnapdict.value["Selected"] as! String
```

Comment: It depends. Are `self.nom` and the other properties optional or non-optional? And `snapshot.value` is certainly not reference type. Cast it to `[String:Any]`

Comment: All keys are no optional

Comment: Then assign default values e.g. `self.nom = (dtlSnapdict.value["Nom"] as? String) ?? ""`

Comment: Honestly, this is a perfect use-case for codable object. The best part, you don't even have to force cast. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55047138/swift-decode-string-any

Comment: I made the changes, but I have to wait until Friday to test because Firebase is used so far

Comment: I had a test it's correct. Thank you for your help. My request may be closing